# Errors in benchmark code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

Flipflop structural code and test bench code

I don't know where I have made a mistake. I am getting few errors in the output.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module t_ff (
input clk,t,rst_n,
output reg q);

    always@(posedge clk ,negedge rst_n)
    begin
        if (!rst_n)
            q <= 1'b0;
        else if(t)
            q <= ~q;
        else
            q <= q;
    end

endmodule
```

@@@test bench@@@@

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module tb_tff;
reg RST_n, CLK,T;
wire Q;

t_ff TFF (.clk(CLK) ,.rst_n(RST_n) ,.q( Q ),.t(T));

 initial begin
 RST_n = 1'b0;
 CLK =1'b0;
 T =1'b0;
  #5 RST_n = 1'b1;
  #13 RST_n = 1'b0;
 #7 RST_n = 1'b1;
  #45 $finish;
 end

 always #3 CLK = ~CLK;
 always #6 T = ~T;

always @(posedge CLK ,negedge RST_n)
  $strobe("time =%0t \t INPUT VALUES \t T =%b RST_n =%b \t OUTPUT VALUES 
Q=%d",$time,T,RST_n,Q);

endmodule
```

Getting the errors like this:

> Error-[V2KS] Verilog IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used
>
> TFlipflop.v, 4    Verilog 2000 IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used : Combined
>   port and type     declaration.    Please compile with +v2k to support
>   this construct.
>
> Error-[V2KS] Verilog IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used
>
> TFlipflop.v, 4    Verilog 2000 IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used : Ansi style
>   port declaration.    Please compile with +v2k to support this
>   construct.
>
> Error-[V2KS] Verilog IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used
>
> TFlipflop.v, 6    Verilog 2000 IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used : Comma
>   separated sensitivity lists.    Please compile with +v2k to support
>   this construct.
>
> Parsing design file 'test_TFlipflop.v'
>
> Error-[V2KS] Verilog IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used
>
> test_TFlipflop.v, 21    Verilog 2000 IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used :
>   Comma separated sensitivity lists.    Please compile with +v2k to
>   support this construct.
>
> 4 errors CPU time: .036 seconds

Comment: Kindly show and mark these lines in your code.

Comment: What simulator and version are you using? Sounds like you need to add `+v2k` to your compiler options. Modern simulators have enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your simulator **needs an update**. Try a newer version. All these are **valid ANSI styles**. Following are the error reasons and some *workarounds*:

```
Error-[V2KS] Verilog IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used
TFlipflop.v, 4
Verilog 2000 IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used : Combined port and type 
 declaration.
```

I guess the error says `output reg q` is not valid, even though it is a valid ANSI style. So, do something like this:

```
module t_ff (input clk,t,rst_n,output q);
reg q;

// Alternate Non-ANSI style
module t_ff (clk,t,rst_n,q);
input clk,t,rst_n;
output q;
reg q;
```

Next is :

```
Error-[V2KS] Verilog IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used
TFlipflop.v, 6
Verilog 2000 IEEE 1364-2000 syntax used : Comma separated sensitivity lists.
```

This is also **valid synthesizable declaration**, either use as follows, in both testbench and design:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) // use or
```

You can also add `+v2k` switch and try again. I've simulated your code at [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RCR), and works completely well.